# Nova rota não funciona codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Olá, criei um controller que chama uma função com uma variavel no index, mechi na rota funciona perfeitamente, só que agora criei outra função dentro deste mesmo controler e ele não funciona, sempre que chamo a segunda função ele cai direto na index. Como eu faço pra chamar a segunda função deste controller?, se puderem me ajudar agradeço.

Meu controller Home:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct(){

        parent::__construct();
         $this->load->model('painel_model');
    }

    public function index($meta_link=NULL)
    {  
        if (!$meta_link) {
            redirect('/', 'refresh');
        }
         //informações da pagina
        $data['titulo'] = $produto->nome_produto;
        $data['dados_painel'] = $query;     
        $data['view'] = 'painel/software/info';
        $data['produto'] = $produto;
        $data['fotos'] = $this->painel_model->getFotos($produto->id);

         //carrego template
         $this->load->view('painel/software/template', $data);  
    }

    public function checkout()
    {  
        //Dados da loja
        $query = $this->painel_model->getDadosPainel();

        //menu topo
        $data['categorias'] = $this->painel_model->getCategorias();

         //informações da pagina
          $data['titulo'] = 'Checkout';
          $data['dados_painel'] = $query;       
          $data['view'] = 'painel/checkout/baixar';

         //carrego template
         $this->load->view('painel/checkout/template', $data);  
    }

}
```

Minha routes:

```
//toras pagina home
$route['home/(:any)'] = 'home/index/$1';
```

Se eu chamo a function index, ele funciona perfeito, agora se chamo a checkout ele não funciona, fica sempre retornando a index, como faço pra chamar a checkout pela rota? se puderem me ajudar agradeço.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## O porquê do comportamento não esperado

O comportamento de apenas retornar a view do método index do seu controller Home, ou seja, chamar apenas o método index, ocorre por que você definiu uma única rota no arquivo `application/config/routes.php` que possui, após a `/`, um wildcard type `(:any)` que irá mapear URIs no seguinte padrão...

- seudominio.com/home
- seudominio.com/home/checkout
- seudominio.com/home/qualqueroutracoisa

**sempre** para seu método index do controller Home.

Para entender melhor o funcionamento das rotas no framework pode acessar a [documentação oficial](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html).

## A solução

Para que você consiga chamar o método checkout, basta **modificar a rota existente** para resolver apenas para o método index do controller Home e **adicionar uma nova rota** para o método checkout. Então só precisa modificar seu arquivo de rotas que, de acordo com o contexto apresentado na pergunta, ficaria assim:

```
//toras pagina home
$route['home'] = 'home/index/$1';
$route['home/checkout'] = 'home/checkout';
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Fiz umas mudanças de logica funcionou com suas dicas. valew amigo